# Conflict with other function methods when locally run

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Not sure, if somebody else has faced the same problem.

I have a solution with a couple of Azure Function APP in it.
So when i run the solution locally, with multiple start up projects, i ensure that there is only one azure function that boots when i run the project.

Now am facing a problem, were when i run the project, azure function core tools open in command but it tries to call methods/activities in another azure function app which i have not even run.

Example below

[image]

If you see the pic, all the content in yellow is from another function app which is not even running at the moment.

This is causing so much nuisance when i try to debug the function app locally.

Please advise, if you have experienced and fixed this problem.

Comment: Are you referencing the dll where the other function is located in?

Comment: *i ensure that there is only one azure function that boots when i run the project* -> how?

Comment: I set that in set start up projects!

Comment: it would be easier if you put your code...